# how stop javascript function pageScroll

Tags: javascript, function

I have this simple script for auto scroll on a html web page:

```
     function pageScroll() {
          window.scrollBy(0,10); 
             scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',20);
}
```

I want the scroll to stop when page arrives to bottom so that the users can easily go back to top; I know I can use function pageScrollStop and clearTimeout but I don't know how.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can do this:

```
var pageBottom;
function initScroll() {
    pageBottom = document.body.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight + document.getElementById("footer").offsetHeight + 20;
    pageScroll();
}
function pageScroll() {
    if (window.scrollY >= pageBottom) return false;
    window.scrollBy(0, 10);
    scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()', 20);
}
```

Change your body onload function to initScroll().

I did this just for better performance, as you can see the pageBottom is calculated only once instead of every time pageScroll() is called...

Comment: @PierreGranger good call! though I'm not sure returning false would clear the previous timeout would it? .. maybe it would be safer to clearTimeout instead?

Comment: If you return before the next setTimeout then you have nothing to cancel, but yes it call 1 more time pageScroll than you solution. as the last more call is instantly canceled i don't think it's a problem, but your solution was probably more "correctly coded" yes. This was just to make it shorter and clearer ;)

Comment: @PierreGranger cool.. I think in this case it doesn't really matter if it's called an extra time..

Comment: this seems to work fine, thank you, but page doesn't scroll to bottom, it stops and can't understand why...

Comment: @user3733023 do you need help debugging this?

Comment: Do you have a link? first thing to try is give your timeout more time, maybe 20 miliseconds is not enough for the function to recompute.. try using 500 just to see if it helps

Comment: I've already tried to increase timeout, it slows down the scroll but it stops as well; please note that I also have the onLoad="pageScroll()" in body. I could put a link on a site if can be useful or send the code

Comment: http://www.aebservizieditoriali.com clik on link: you'll see scroll starting and stopping before bottom; some images are missed, I can upload if needed. Many thanks!!

Comment: hmm are you on a mobile device? because on desktop I don't get a scrollbar at all.. oh sorry never mind.. I clicked ont he link now :)

Comment: Ok I know why this happends.. because your footer is fixed position and is therefor not calculated in the height of the document.. I'll update my answer

Comment: pretty perfect: stops just before bottom...I've uploaded the link, if you please

Comment: @user3733023 yes, I forgot to also include the 10px top and bottom margins you have on BODY.. so I'm going to edit and just add 20 pixels manually.. if you want to calculate the margins in pure js it's a little hassle for cross browser.. I'd use jQuery, but if you must have this in pure js code let me know..

Comment: I forgot them too! I think I'm gonna delate those margins, anyway with +20 is working great

Answer (score 0):

```
clearTimeout(scrolldelay);
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Simply evaluate the scroll position (jQuery does it beautifully) inside the `pageScroll` function and if the page has already reached the bottom then exit the recursion loop by clearing the time out

Comment: My point is, you refer to jquery in your answer.. the OP says 'I know I can use function pageScrollStop and clearTimeout but I don't know how' ... if he doesn't know how to use clearTimeout, he probably doesn't know what jquery is.. Your answer basically says: simply go learn how to use jquery and clearTimeout.. *which in the end does make alota sense though ;)

Comment: "simply go learn how to use jquery and clearTimeout"...you got that right mate. If he doesn't want to do it, well, why bother with web development if he's not willing to learn the basics?

Comment: actually in this case I'm using JS, anyway, thanks a lot